# All combination of groups of 2 or 3 people from a list of persons [Python]

Tags: python, combinations

I have an issue.
I have to create all division of groups of 2 or 3 people with no repetition (not 2 times the same division).
For example I have 6 members : [a,b,c,d,e,f]
The code should respond : 
ab cd ef
ab ce df
ab cf de
abc def 
...

I have already the code to make all combinaison but only for groups of 2 and I don't know how to do for groups of 3 and 2 (for example ab cde if we have 5 persons)

```
lst =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

def all_pairs(lst):
if len(lst) < 2:
    yield []
    return
if len(lst) % 2 == 1:
    # Handle odd length list
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for result in all_pairs(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
            yield result
else:
    a = lst[0]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        pair = [a,lst[i]]
        for rest in all_pairs(lst[1:i]+lst[i+1:]):
            yield [pair] + rest
print(list(all_pairs(lst)))
```

Comment: import itertools; result = (subset for option in (2,3) for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, option))

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools to do this

```
import itertools

lst =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
for L in range(0, len(lst)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, L):
        if len(subset) == 2 or len(subset) == 3 :
            print(subset)
```

Comment: Soory I think I didn't explain well the project. 
I want all division of groups for example :
[ab,cd,ef]
[ab,ce,df]
[ab,cf,de]
...